# In the context of eigendecomposition, are the areas before and after distort same? I guess yes, but how to prove this?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

this image coms from [The deep learning book Figure 2.3](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/linear_algebra.html)

[image]

this chapter says

> By observing the way that A distorts the unit circle, we can see that
>   it scales space in direction v(i)by λi.

the question is:

are the areas before and after multiplication same? I guess yes, but how to prove this?

Comment: The areas are always the same only for matrices with unit determinant. More generally, determinant gives tge ratio of areas before and after applying the operation. For diagonalizable matrices, it is simply the product of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the areas before and after multiplication are not always the same, in fact they almost always are not.

Looking at your image more closely your unit circle started off having an area of $\pi$, but after you applied your linear transformation both of the unit eigenvectors($v_1$ and $v_2$) got scaled to the length of their eigenvalues $λ_1$ and $λ_2$, so you are left with an ellipse that has area $λ_1λ_2\pi$.

This tells use that the areas will be scaled by the product of all the eigenvalues, which makes sense since it is also the determinant of the matrix which defines this transformation.

Answer (score 1):

They are not.  Consider the following matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

This matrix has eigenvalues of $\{1,0\}$

The corresponding picture will be a line segment with 0 area (since the smaller axis will have length $0$).  And thus, its area will be $0$.

Comment: Why isn’t 0 technically an eigenvalue?

Comment: 0 is definitely an eigenvalue of that matrix, unless you are using some very unusual definition.

Comment: @NateEldredge  You're right.  My mistake.  I'll fix it.  (I've seen where sometimes 0 isn't considered an eigenvalue, but I see now that that isn't the most common definition.)